# Remove value if part of vector, and if so accumulate it to another variable

Tags: rust

I currently do it this way:

```rs
// v is a vector with thousands of sorted unsigned int value.

let mut total = 0;

// [...]
// some loop
    let a = 5;
    if v.iter().any(|&x| x == a as u16) {
        total += a;
        v.retain(|&x| x != a as u16);
    }
// end loop
```

But it is quite inefficient since I iterate twice over `v` (although perhaps the compiler would catch this and optimize), isn't it a more elegant way to do it with Rust?

*NB: The vector is sorted and contains no duplicate values if it can help*

Comment: Is the point of `retain` to remove exactly 1 item from the vector? Or might there be multiple values in `v` that == 5`?

Comment: only 1, sorry no duplicate value also, perhaps I should use an (ordered) set instead of a vector?

Comment: I don't get it, there is no duplicate value ?!? so while do you do that ? Please do a better MCVE

Comment: I want to trigger a function once the vector is empty. This is a MCVE.

Comment: Sorted and no dupes? Maybe you want a `BTreeSet`. `if set.remove(&a) { total += a; }`

Comment: would it be more efficient than the answer of Stargateur?

Comment: For just one search-and-remove operation, for a sufficiently large dataset, yes (`O(log n)` vs. `O(n)`). I encourage you to read [the `std::collections` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/); it has a nice section on "When Should You Use Which Collection?"

Comment: Are you sure? binary search is (also) O(log n)

Comment: it's really hard to answer, a HashSet could also be a good answer, you will have to do your own benchmark to have a definitive answer.

Comment: I just checked the documentation, btree insert and retrieve items using binary search to keep element sorted, so Vector will be faster to create a set of 0..n values. For the retrieval they will be equivalent since they use the same function.

Comment: For retrieval `remove` dominates, which is O(n) for `Vec` unless you can guarantee the element being removed is at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly your request, here a solution:

- You say your vector is sorted so you can use [`binary_search()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.binary_search)
- And so you can use [`remove()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove)

```rust
fn foo(data: &mut Vec<u16>) -> u64 {
    let mut total: u64 = 0;
    let mut a = 0;

    while data.len() > 0 {
        if let Ok(i) = data.binary_search(&a) {
            total += data.remove(i) as u64;
        }
        a += 1;
    }

    total
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 3, 8, 9, 46];

    assert_eq!(foo(&mut data), 67);
}
```

This keep the vector sorted while removing, note that this is a dummy example. If you don't care about sorting you can use [`swap_remove()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove) but this disallow the use of `binary_search()`.

It's hard to say what would be the better.

Comment: You understood very well, thank you @Stargateur and +1 for thinking about using binary search!

Comment: Still seems like a lot of complicated traffic, especially if the vector is sorted and you're starting from the bottom: you're going to look for 1, if you find it you're then going to remove it from the vector *and shift all following items back one*. Why not just [sum()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#tymethod.sum) the vector (with an intermediate adapter)  then [clear()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.clear) it? Or if you really want to do it by hand, [Vec::pop()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.pop) as long as it succeeds?

Comment: @Masklinn as I said the question doesn t have a MCVE so I create a dummy example

Comment: @Stargateur yeah sorry that was intended to be for OP not you, as they're apparently happy with your solution which is more or less a complicated way to do `data.drain().map(|v| v as u64).sum()` no?